# How to create Card list with multiple Sizes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm3n5.png)I want to make Card list for products with multiple sizes like if the builder crossAxisCount:2,
one should be square card and the other is rectangle card to seem catchy to eye

i tried to add the sizes by my self for each element with Random and was not the best solution

Comment: do you have a ui design for that? If yes, upload it for reference.

Comment: how to upload the photo here ? sir

Comment: i uploaded the image in the question description

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this package `flutter_staggered_grid_view`

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

it will help you to use random size cards